# Typescript type with keys strictly made of a string union type

Tags: typescript

I need to create a type with multiple properties where each property has its own type (i.e. it is not guaranteed that all properties have the same type. I also need to make sure that all property names are strictly from another string union type.

Here's the example of what I need to achieve

```
type Operations = "create:op" | "update:op" | "delete:op";

// Next three type defs only to demonstrate that all of them are different and 
// they don't have any common ancestor, etc.
type CreateOperationParams = {
    foo: string
}

type UpdateOperationParams = {
    bar: boolean
}

type DeleteOperationParams = {
    baz: number
}

// All properties in this type must be from Operations
// and every item from Operations must be present here
// as a property
type OperationParams = {
    "create:op"?: CreateOperationParams | false
    "update:op"?: UpdateOperationParams | false
    "delete:op"?: DeleteOperationParams | false
}
```

If `OperationsParams` is coded entirely manually then it very easy to make a mistake like this

```
type OperationParams = {
    // Property name is not one of Operations, a dot is used instead of a colon.
    // This case must raise TS error. Another error should be that the correct
    // value "create:op" is not present in type properties 
    "create.op"?: CreateOperationParams | false   
    ...
}
```

Above is a simplified example of what I actually have. I've got about 40 different values in `Operations` type some of them having somewhat long names with some special characters like colons or dots. I obviously could just carefully copy and paste all of them into `OperationsParams` type and define correct types for each but the likeliness of an error is very high especially when `Operations` changes.

Is there any way to implement my scenario but enforce that every property of `OperationsParams` is from `Operations` union type and no other properties may be added? Also to ensure that all items in `Operations` are present in `OperationsParams` as type properties?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the type which catch your intent:

```
type OpParam = CreateOperationParams | UpdateOperationParams | DeleteOperationParams;
type OperationParams = Partial<Record<Operations, OpParam | false>>
```

I added `false` as that was in your example.
Here is the full code - [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYBLA9gOwM5QLxQCIBjeCZCALjTAKgB9CBXMAE3KpvsJYgBsJglagQDcAWABQkgPTSoAOQgAPYFGAALUtFCQoPAGY5MvEGrR6IAW0xZgSQWvXIoiXryhp9jqy9J6U+voQpBiqiBgsUDJyGhCmLJgA5KpOAG7Q4aZEaJbWGC4YRBC2aPAANFACRAB0kjrQAMKk5HDByOgYAAqISJY4+ADeklAjUPpoaBRQtvAoGADmkgC+knXg0ACqrC0I7Zjdvf1QQxKjUABGPVPnE-zhy6sS9VAAInwCEK32HQeIfXjHYajS4ALymGEYlnOwQeUgksigAEE3FAwPBqMFUMUoHNHCgcM9LIxbBdoPp0ZZYLtUDZogVIhB0vBTChBJTyTkqW0adgoESSdDUaQsBBQlB1MEIHTEDhEEKMfBQGtdHBfpT8E0yIIvnsuj0-jgGFs2NrqT99f8GG9+KbuebDuInusud99hajgdUK4ADwAJQg2XgLG9Op5WAqVLVXH0rhFAD4449stgwlNQ-aDQCTiNEiQtUIwIkpgNLvApnZGBAVhIllAEWgANZJmyqc5ps1uw5ZoG55qCDhF46l8vwStLMo9pSDxIAd3RCygDbiiWWdbkc8w80XcWbKagRHbds7mcGPbz7Gog5LVzUo6rE9OUESzBNBenG4XqVclZXNbXUA-Lcv14SsgA)

What we are doing here is:

- we say we need a Record with keys from `Operations` type
- we say values can be one of possible Param types ( I put it into OpParam )
- we wrap it by Partial to make properties optional

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for. I need to ensure properties on type definition, not on an object of this type. Also, I'd rather avoid union type on each property and I'd rather stay with a specific type for each prop

Answer (score 0):

This may fulfil your criteria?

```js
type CreateParams = {
  "create:op"?: {
    foo: string
  }
}

type UpdateParams = {
  "update:op"?: {
    bar: boolean
  }
}

type DeleteParams = {
  "delete:op"?: {
    baz: number
  }
}

type OperationParams = CreateParams & UpdateParams & DeleteParams;

type Operations = keyof OperationParams;

const goodParams: OperationParams = {
  "create:op": {
    foo: "hey"
  },
  "delete:op": {
    baz: 3
  },
  "update:op": {
    bar: true
  }
}

const brokenParams: OperationParams = {
  //shows a compiler error as requested
  "create.op": {
    foo: "hey"
  },
  "delete:op": {
    baz: 3
  },
  "update:op": {
    bar: true
  }
}
```